# Spring self injection for transactions

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions

In Spring you can't simply call `@Transactional` method from the same instance, because of AOP-proxy thing. Would it be nice idea to make a self injection and call that method from self proxy instance? Do you see any drawbacks?

Comment: There are cases when it is most elegant solution available , I have used it couple of times. Spring 4.3 introduced new feature to autowire self, IMHO spring support proves it is not a bad practice.

Comment: Maybe you can also use an exposed proxy instance via `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true"/>` or `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy = true)`, see [SPR-10454](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10454) and [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api//org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html#exposeProxy--).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is totally ok.
Moreover there was a [Jira ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13096) for supporting this feature using `@Autowired` annotations. It's fixed in `Spring 4.3+` versions. However for xml-based configuration or using `@Resource` annotation it's working in the earlier versions.

You can see the discussion bellow this ticket. `@Transactional` is [one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13096#issuecomment-453360246) of the use case for this:

> Particularly interested in @Async and @Transactional use cases.