# @Transactional with handling error and db-inserts in catch block (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I would like to rollback a transaction for the data in case of errors and at the same time write the error to db.

I can't manage to do with Transactional Annotations.

Following code produces a runtime-error (1/0) and still writes the data into the db. And also writes the data into the error table.

I tried several variations and followed similar questions in StackOverflow but I didn't succeed to do.

Anyone has a hint, how to do?

```
@Service
public class MyService{

       @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
        public void updateData() {
            try{
                processAndPersist();    // <- db operation with inserts
                int i = 1/0; // <- Runtime error
            }catch (Exception e){
                persistError()
                trackReportError(filename, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    
    
        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public void persistError(String message) {
            persistError2Db(message); // <- db operation with insert
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the way to throw an exception in `updateData()` method to rollback a transaction. And you need to not rollback `persistError()` transaction at the same time.

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
        public void updateData() {
            try{
                processAndPersist();    // <- db operation with inserts
                int i = 1/0; // <- Runtime error
            }catch (Exception e){
                persistError()
                trackReportError(filename, e.getMessage());
                throw ex; // if throw error here, will not work

            }
        }
```

Just throwing an error will not help because `persistError()` will have the same transaction as `updateData()` has. Because `persistError()` is called using `this` reference, not a reference to a proxy.

**Options to solve**

1. Using self reference.
2. Using self injection [Spring self injection for transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280460/spring-self-injection-for-transactions)
3. Move the call of `persistError()` outside `updateData()` (and transaction). Remove `@Transactional` from `persistError()` (it will not work) and use transaction of `Repository` in `persistError2Db()`.
4. Move `persistError()` to a separate serface. It will be called using a proxy in this case.
5. Don't use declarative transactions (with `@Transactional` annotation). Use Programmatic transaction management to set transaction boundaries manually https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch11s06.html

Also keep in mind that `persistError()` can produce error too (and with high probability will do it).

**Using self reference**

You can use self reference to MyService to have a transaction, because you will be able to call not a method of `MyServiceImpl`, but a method of Spring proxy.

```java
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    public void doWork(MyService self) {
        DataEntity data = loadData();

        try {
            self.updateData(data);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error for dataId={}", data.getId(), ex);
            self.persistError("Error");
            trackReportError(filename, ex);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateData(DataEntity data) {
        persist(data);    // <- db operation with inserts
    }

    @Transactional
    public void persistError(String message) {
        try {
            persistError2Db(message); // <- db operation with insert
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error for message={}", message, ex);
        }
    }
}

public interface MyService {

    void doWork(MyService self);
    
    void updateData(DataEntity data);

    void persistError(String message);

}
```

To use

```java
MyService service = ...;
service.doWork(service);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried exactly the way you described, but I got an "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query" error. Is there no other simplier way todo without self referencing? For me this looks 'error-prone'.

Comment: @mcflysoft Yo need to get the service from a Spring Context here `MyService service = ...`. Another way is to move persistError() in a separate service. Better not to call it form an origin transaction.

Comment: @mcflysoft Where did you get that exception?