# JUnit Mock Singleton Class with Environment Variables

Tags: java, junit

I have a singleton Class as follows:

```
 public class PropertiesSingleton {
private static PropertiesSingleton instance;

private static ApplicationContext ctx = new 
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PropertiesConfig.class);

public static PropertiesSingleton getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        synchronized (PropertiesSingleton.class) {
            if(instance == null){
                instance = new PropertiesSingleton();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

public Environment env(){
    return ctx.getEnvironment();
}
}
```

The PropertiesConfig Class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("someComponent")
@PropertySources({@PropertySource("file:${someName}/foo/foo.properties"),
@PropertySource("classPath:Properties")
})
public class PropertiesConfig {
@Autowired
private Environment env;
}
```

And it is being called in Controller as Follows:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/mappingUrl")
public class MappingController{ 
static Environment env = PropertiesSingleton.getInstance().env();
}
```

What I am trying to do is get the mocked value for env in controller and I am trying it following way:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
     MockEnvironment env = new MockEnvironment();
     env.setProperty("serverName", "test");

     PropertiesSingleton environmentMock = 
     PowerMockito.mock(PropertiesSingleton.class);
     Whitebox.setInternalState( PropertiesSingleton.class, "INSTANCE", 
     environmentMock );
     when(environmentMock.getInstance().env())
        .thenReturn(env);        
     }
```

But I get following errors:

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

and looking at stack trace I see following:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [propertiesConfig.class]

org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.

Any help is appreciated......

EDIT:

Here is my full test method--

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
 import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static 
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static 
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PropertiesSingleton.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:someclassPath")
public class MappingControllerTest{

private MockMvc mockMvc;

JSONObject  obj = new JSONObject("{" 
        + "\"_id\": \"184DZ01C\"," 
        + "\"text\": \"textTest\","                  
        + "\"image\" : \"Test.png\"," 
        + "\"link\" : \"www.testFile.com\"," 
        + "\"title\" : \"testTitle\"," 
        + "\"weight\" : \"0\","
        + "}");

public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = new 
MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(), 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));


@InjectMocks
@Spy
 MappingController _mappingController = new MappingController();



@Mock
private Appender logAppender;  



@Mock
private Environment environmentMock;


@Mock
private PropertiesSingleton singletonMock;




 @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
     Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReviewWfEndpoint.class);
     logger.addAppender(logAppender);
     logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);

    }




 @Test
 public void TestReviewWfEndpoint_pass()
  throws Exception {    
    String expectedServer = "test";
    String expectedServerPropertyName = "serverName";

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(PropertiesSingleton.class);
    when(PropertiesSingleton.getInstance()).thenReturn(singletonMock);
    when(singletonMock.env()).thenReturn(environmentMock);
    when(environmentMock.getProperty(expectedServerPropertyName))
    .thenReturn(expectedServer);
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/mappingUrl/map")
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(jString)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))                
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

}

}
```

and in my controller I use env like this:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/mappingUrl")
public class MappingController{ 
static Environment env = PropertiesSingleton.getInstance().env();
@RequestMapping(value="/map", method=RequestMethod.POST, 
produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Object> map(@RequestBody String jsonString){
String environmentName = 
env.getProperty("Constant");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SLF4J is probably loaded by Spring (possibly somewhere in the call stack starting with `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`) but you can ignore that (and will probably disappear after setting up your test correctly).

Anyway, you need to do a few things to completely mock your singleton and return your custom environment instance. Furthermore, with this you no longer need `Whitebox` to update the singleton state, you just define the mock's behavior:

1. use the specific `PowerMockRunner` so that the Powermock "*magic*" can happen
2. suppress the static initialization sections inside the singleton
3. `mockStatic` your singleton (for `getInstance()`)
4. define the expected behavior step by step as Powermock [does not yet support DEEP STUBBING](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/507) (aka `environmentMock.getInstance().env()`)

You can find below a complete example. Please note that in my sources:

- I've used a mock for the environment as well since you did not share `MockEnvironment` (it was also easier for me)
- for brevity, I changed `MappingController` to make `static Environment env` **public** so I can quickly check my expected value (also you did not share the code that uses it). Please do not do this in production

```java
package com.example;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.SuppressStaticInitializationFor;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;

// use a special runner
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// suppress static initialization block in singleton
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.example.PropertiesSingleton")
public class SingletonTest {

    // create the mock to return by getInstance()
    @Mock
    private PropertiesSingleton singletonMock;

    // environment mock for quick test
    @Mock
    private Environment environmentMock;

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() throws Exception {
        String expectedServer = "test";
        String expectedServerPropertyName = "serverName";

        // define behavior
        // please note power mockito does not yet support DEEP STUBBING (https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/507), so multiple "whens" must be used
        mockStatic(PropertiesSingleton.class);
        when(PropertiesSingleton.getInstance()).thenReturn(singletonMock);
        when(singletonMock.env()).thenReturn(environmentMock);
        when(environmentMock.getProperty(expectedServerPropertyName)).thenReturn(expectedServer);

        // invoke the object under test and check results
        assertThat(MappingController.env.getProperty(expectedServerPropertyName), is(expectedServer));
    }
}
```

**P.S.** you may want to consider giving this a quick read: [the benefits of constructor injection vs field injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620000/spring-autowire-on-properties-vs-constructor) (aka `@Autowired Environment env;` in your sample)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still getting org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array. I think that could be because of the PropertiesConfig class not being mocked. I will see what I can do. If there is anything that you would recommend that is appreciated.

Comment: I really wish I could change the code to have dependency injection. The current code in the project makes me want to throw up.

Comment: @briefcasejoe Ummm `org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException` doe not seem to be related to the project, that seems to be an IDE exception of some sort... Can you post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and mention exactly how you are running the test and Eclipse's version? Also what happens if you don't debug the test I wrote and simply run it?

Comment: I am using workspace-sts 3.9.6. To answer few of your previous question. Mockenvironment I am using is from org.springframework.mock.env.MockEnvironment. While digging I realized that they are assigning to org.springframework.core.env.Environment interface from PropertiesSingleton.getInstance().env() in the controller. If i do not debug and run the test I get java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError from PropertiesSingleton.getInstance().env() on restController.

Comment: @briefcasejoe I assume you added `mockStatic(PropertiesSingleton.class);` and saw my note on deep stubbing? If yes, then please share a complete test class that reproduces the issue. Strip any sensitive information out, rename packages, etc, but  please keep the imports. We need to see how/what is configured and run.

Comment: @briefcasejoe Try replacing `PrepareForTest` with `SuppressStaticInitializationFor` like in my sample and let me know what you get. I'm on the road now, will check back later

Comment: still gives java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at the static Environment.

Comment: @briefcasejoe That is very weird, I'm fairly certain the example I posted should work just fine. Can you create a new test starting from my sample, make sure it works, then slowly add your custom pieces, and re-test until it fails again?

Comment: So, the error is because the test is not able to initialize @PropertySources({@PropertySource("file:${catalina.home}/foo/foo.properties"), in the PropertyConfig.java file. I have no clue how I will be able to mock that in unit test.

Comment: @briefcasejoe That shouldn't even happen if you suppress the static initialization for the `PropertiesSingleton` and then use mocks. Is there any other place that would trigger a spring context to actually be loaded?