# Constructor Injection in configuration classes in Sprin5

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was trying to create a configuration class

```
 @Configuration
 public class AppConfig {

 private final SomeBean someBean;
 private final AnotherBean anotherBean;

 @Autowired
 public AppConfig(SomeBean someBean, AnotherBean anotherBean) {
     this.someBean = someBean;
     this.anotherBean = anotherBean;
 }     

}
```

Another approach with

```
@Configuration
 public class AppConfig {

 @Autowired
 private final SomeBean someBean;

 @Autowired
 private final AnotherBean anotherBean;



}
```

Not sure which one I have to go for.

I have seen many codes with the second approach, but not with the first approach.

Any reason for this?

Comment: Here you can find answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620000/spring-autowire-on-properties-vs-constructor

Comment: That's related to Component, I am asking for Configuration

Comment: Well, you are performing dependency injection, no matter if you are in component or in configuration, you are doing same stuff so the same pros and cons will appear.

Comment: Any issues with the bean instantiation order?

Comment: You can try both ways in project. I haven't experienced any problems.