# How to create a test in Springt Boot that calls a service which includes constructor injection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit

I'm trying to write a test in a Spring-Boot project. My problem is that I can't use my service that includes a constructor injection.

Depending on what I try I get errors like `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`s or `NullPointerException`s.

My first try was to change the constructor injection in my service to a field injection. But after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620000/spring-autowire-on-properties-vs-constructor) I decided to change it back to the previous way.
Then I searched for examples but couldn't find something that was helpful.

Following are the relevant code snippets. If more code is needed I would provide it.

The service class with the constructor injection:

**PlayerServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class PlayerServiceImpl implements PlayerService {

    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;
    private CompanyService companyService;
    private CompanyResourceService companyResourceService;

    @Autowired
    public PlayerServiceImpl(PlayerRepository thePlayerRepository, CompanyService theCompanyService,
                             CompanyResourceService theCompanyResourceService) {
        this.playerRepository = thePlayerRepository;
        this.companyService = theCompanyService;
        this.companyResourceService = theCompanyResourceService;
    }

...

}
```

The test class im trying to create:

**PlayerServiceImplIntegrationTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PlayerServiceImplIntegrationTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class PlayerServiceImplTestContextConfiguration {

        private PlayerRepository playerRepository;
        private CompanyService companyService;
        private CompanyResourceService companyResourceService;

        @Bean
        public PlayerService playerService() {
            return new PlayerServiceImpl(playerRepository, companyService, companyResourceService);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private PlayerService playerService;

    @MockBean
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Player max = new Player("MaxMustang", "test123", "MaxMustang",
                "max.mustang@test.com", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), 1, 0,
                new BigDecimal("0.00"), new BigDecimal("0.00"), 0, 0);

        Mockito.when(playerRepository.findByUserName(max.getUserName()))
                .thenReturn(max);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenFindById_thenReturnPlayer() {
        String userName = "MaxMustang";

        Player found = playerService.findByUserName(userName);

        assertThat(found.getUserName()).isEqualTo(userName);
    }
}
```

In my test, I'm trying to create a player object and receive it. It's just my first test in Spring Boot. And my main goal was to just get the test running. 
And the original test is from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) from "5. Mocking with @MockBean". But while experimenting around, I added or changed a few things.

If I missed a post pointing at the same problem I would be glad to be informed about that.

Also, I would appreciate it if someone can tell me if the arguments in the constructor of my service are too much or still in an "ok" range.

Comment: you have two classes creating beans of type PlayerService and in one you are passing null objects ? ignore the TestConfiguration class and try it

Comment: Ok know it works. I thought, that I have to implement a `@TestConfiguration` class. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the configuration bean primary and also use constructor injection on that method:

```
    @TestConfiguration
    static class PlayerServiceImplTestContextConfiguration {

      @Bean
      @Primary
      public PlayerService playerService(PlayerRepository playerRepository,
            CompanyService companyService, CompanyResourceService companyResourceService) {
        return new PlayerServiceImpl(playerRepository, companyService, companyResourceService);
      }
    }
```

Without primary you will have two beans of same type floating around and you dont use `@Qualifier` here. Also you cannot `@Autowire` beans in a configuration class thats why you need to use constructor injection.

Comment: That worked, too! Thanks, but could you tell me which is the better approach? With or without a `@TestConfiguration`? And does `@Primary` and the fact that my `@TestConfiguration` class is static affect my service or controller classes?

Comment: If you cannot use MockBean as in this case @TestConfiguration is fine