# Error building project spring org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm learning spring and I'm doing a basic project that consults a table and shows the rows through a service.

At the time of building the project I have the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personaService' defined in file [D:\Daniel\Proyecto-Catalogo\backend\cyberbuzon\target\classes\com\verasoftec\cyberbuzon\negocio\services\PersonaService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.verasoftec.cyberbuzon.modelo.Persona com.verasoftec.cyberbuzon.negocio.repository.PersonaRepository.edit(com.verasoftec.cyberbuzon.modelo.Persona)! No property edit found for type Persona!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

...
[image]
My class:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you use the @ComponentScan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to create a `PersonaService` interface and packed the intended methods into your `PersonaRepository` instead. And the problem with the methods you put in there is that they don't follow the pattern of the `JpaRepository`. Take a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries) article to find out how to declare methods in your `PersonaRepository`.

To fix your problem you could easily just delete the methods in your `PersonaRepository`.

```
public interface PersonaRepository extends JpaRepository<Persona, Integer> { }
```

You already used the right method of your `PersonaRepository` in your `PersonaService` (`personaRepository.findAll()`), so you just have to add your methods that you removed from your `PersonaRepository` into your `PersonaService` and implement the corresponding methods from your repository like `findById(int id)`, `save(Persona persona)` and `delete(int id)`.

Comment: Thanks Constantin, the project building sucess.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PersonaService` is missing the `@Autowired` annotation. So your `personaRepository` can’t be created through dependency injection.

You have two options:

1. You can annotate your `personaRepository` field with `@Autowired`
2. or you can annotate your `PersonaService` constructor with `@Autowired`

Same goes for your `PersonaResource` and your `personaService` field.

I would recommend to annotate your constructor. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620000/spring-autowire-on-properties-vs-constructor) post for more information about that.

So in the end your code should look like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class PersonaService {

   private final PersonaRespository personaRepository;

   @Autowired
   public PersonaService(PersonaRepository personaRepository) {
      this.personaRepository = personaRepository;
   }

   ...
}
```

And your `PersonaResource` should look like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/personas")
public class PersonaResource {

   private final PersonaService personaService;

   @Autowired
   public PersonaResource(PersonaService personaService) {
      this.personaService = personaService;
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made the adjustment according to what you tell me, but the problem remains.
The same error is still displayed.