# Call singleton class in spring boot rest api controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, design-patterns

I am new to spring framework. I have to use spring boot and have a rest controller as below :-

```
@RestController
public class StatisticsController {

    private TransactionCache transactionCache;

    public StatisticsController(TransactionCache transactionCache) {
        this.transactionCache = transactionCache;
    }

    @PostMapping("/tick")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addInstrumentTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody InstrumentTransaction instrumentTransaction) {
        transactionCache.addTransaction(instrumentTransaction);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

and I have a class which needs to be singleton :-

```
@Component
public class TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl implements TransactionCache {

    private static TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl instance;

    public static TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl getInstance(){

        if(Objects.isNull(instance)){
            synchronized (TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl.class) {
                if(Objects.isNull(instance)){
                    instance = new TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl() {}
```

I want to know the correct way to call this singleton class in my rest controller. I know that by default the scope of a bean in spring is singleton. Is this the correct way to call the singleton class in rest controller?

```
@RestController
public class StatisticsController {

    private TransactionCache transactionCache;

    public StatisticsController(TransactionCache transactionCache) {
        this.transactionCache = transactionCache;
    }

    @PostMapping("/tick")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addInstrumentTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody InstrumentTransaction instrumentTransaction) {
        transactionCache.addTransaction(instrumentTransaction);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

or

We need to call it using the getInstance() method? Also do we need to explicitly have the getInstance method in the TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl class?

Comment: Annotating the class with @Component will make it singleton.

Answer (score 4):

One of the major advantages of container injection is that you can get the benefits of singleton semantics without all the serious problems of "hard" singletons (such as difficulty testing). Get rid of the `getInstance` manual business and let Spring take care of ensuring that a single instance is created and used for the context.

Comment: Which means that spring will take care of making the TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl  singleton and so we need not have the get instance method. Also we can simply autowire this bean in the rest controller?

Comment: Don't we also need a private contructor in the class - private TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl() {}

Comment: @CodeMaster Spring makes sure that the bean takes on the singleton _role_: Only one is used for the application. Physically, it's still an ordinary class that you _can_ create multiple copies of, and this _is a good thing_ for testing and other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification: By default, the spring IOC container will create only one instance per bean definition, unless if you specified otherwise using the `@Scope` stereotype. But if you create an instance using `getInstance()` the bean pre-processors and post-processors will not work correctly on that bean definition. And also you can use the `@Autowired` stereotype to inject a bean definition as needed and if you have different implementations for the same definition you can use the `@Qualifier` stereotype to specify the implementation that you need to inject, alternatively, you can use the constructor injection to inject your bean definition as needed without auto wiring as mentioned here [Spring @Autowire on Properties vs Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620000/spring-autowire-on-properties-vs-constructor)

Comment: Thanks. Which means that the code above which i have mentioned is correct way?

Comment: yes and don't use getInstance() when using any dependency injection framework because it should be handled by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to the answers above. However, if you want to preserve further instantiation of the class in your code (or you want to keep your specific implementation of singleton), you can do it with `getInstance()`.

Firstly, get rid of `@Component` annotation in your class:

```java
// @Component
public class TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl implements TransactionCache {

    private static TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl instance;

    public static TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl getInstance(){

        if(Objects.isNull(instance)){
            synchronized (TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl.class) {
                if(Objects.isNull(instance)){
                    instance = new TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private TransactionStatisticsCacheImpl() {}
}
```

Then, you may instantiate your singleton `@Bean` by defining `@Configuration` class - this way your bean would get managed by spring container.

```java
@Configuration
public class SingletonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TransactionCache transactionCache() {
        return TransactionCacheImpl.getInstance();
    }

}
```

Eventually, you can have your singleton injected in your RestController using `@Autowired`.

```java
@RestController
public class StatisticsController {

    private TransactionCache transactionCache;

    @Autowired
    public StatisticsController(TransactionCache transactionCache) {
        this.transactionCache = transactionCache;
    }

    @PostMapping("/tick")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addInstrumentTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody InstrumentTransaction instrumentTransaction) {
        transactionCache.addTransaction(instrumentTransaction);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```