# Spring Boot @Autowired on Variable or Constructor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have an Service Class and a Controller Class:

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return List.of(new Student(1L,
                "Vitor",
                "email@gmail.com",
                LocalDate.of(1993, Month.JANUARY, 6),
                28));
    }
}
```

On the controller what is the difference (practical and/or theoretical) between the 2 implementations below?
(Both works well on my tests)

1: @Autowired direct on the Service object.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentService.getStudents();
    }
}
```

2: @Autowired on the constructor

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/student")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentService.getStudents();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620000/spring-autowire-on-properties-vs-constructor/40620318

Comment: @Nicolas125841, missed that post. Answered. Thanks.

Comment: Property injection

Pros
Reflects the power of Spring dependency injection
less code to write

Cons
Can Not mark dependency as final 
unsafe code
more complicated to test

Construction injection

Pros
Can mark dependency as final which is not possible while injecting properties using property injection
You don't need reflection to set the dependencies
safe code
easy to test
Cons
Coupling your class with your dependency, in fact you cannot instantiate an object without passing its dependencies from the constructor
more code to write