# How to retrieve data in spring boot without passing any variable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How to retrieve a list of  data in spring boot without passing any variable. We are passing only URL for the GET request.

For example, in below code I am passing "roll no" and it is working fine, it is fetching corresponding student detail.

```
 @GetMapping{"/fetch/{rollNo}")
   
   public List<StudentDetail> findStudentDeatilbyRollNo (@PathVariable String rollNo){
    return StudentService.findStudentDetailByRollNo(rollNo);
  }
```

But when I want to fetch all student data without passing parameter it is giving me error "**Non-static method 'fetchAllStudentDetail()' can not be referenced from a static context**"

```
@GetMapping{"/allStudentDetails")
   
   public List<StudentDetail> fetchAllStudentDeatil(){
    return StudentService.fetchAllStudentDeatil();
  }
```

Someone, please help me with the problem.

Comment: It seems that `findStudentDetailByRollNo` is `static` , and `fetchAllStudentDeatil` isn't .

Comment: @Arnaud yes, but what is the solution, if I want to fetch student Details without passing any variable?

Comment: Make both static?

Comment: @Christopher how to doo that?

Comment: Just add the `static` keyword to the method's signature , e.g `public static List<Student> fetchAllStudentDeatil`. Also while you are here, you may want to fix the typo in the method's name :) .

Comment: @Christopher Thank you , But in Controller class "fetchAllStudentDeatil" is non-static . I don't want to make service ,repo or entity  class static because there are many other methods depending on those classes. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Rajeev Do you mean `findStudentDeatilbyRollNo ` is static but `fetchAllStudentDeatil` is not? Maybe show us your `StudentService.class`

Comment: In your service fetchAllStudentDeatil is static. Make that public.

Comment: @AjayKumar No, it is not. It is public

Comment: Please show your service code here then. That is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you are trying to call a non static method in a static way :

To fix that, try to make this method static.

```
StudentService.fetchAllStudentDeatil()
```

To make it static you add the ***static*** word

```
public static List<StudentDetail> fetchAllStudentDeatil()
```

Comment: how to make it static?

Comment: you have to add the static word @Rajeev

Comment: Thank you , But in Controller class "fetchAllStudentDeatil" is non-static . I don't want to make service ,repo or entity class methods static because there are many other methods depending on those classes. Is there any other way?

Comment: This should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues in your code, follow below steps to resolve.

1. In your RestController class autowire `StudentService`.

Example 1:

> ```
> @Autowired  
> private StudentService studentService;
> ```

Example 2:

> ```
> private final StudentService studentService;
>
> @Autowired
> public RestControllerClassName(StudentService studentService){
>     this.studentService = studentService;
> }
> ```

Read more: [Spring @Autowire on Properties vs Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620000/spring-autowire-on-properties-vs-constructor/40620318)

2. Add `@Service` in the `StudentService` class.
3. Remove static from both the methods in `StudentService` `fetchAllStudentDeatil()` and `findStudentDetailByRollNo(rollNo)`.
4. Finally in your RestController, use `studentService.fetchAllStudentDeatil()` and `studentService.fetchAllStudentDeatil(rollNo)`
5. Optional, correct the typo in `Deatil`

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the function fetchAllStudentDeatil inside student service where you are retrieving all the entries in your table  ;

```
static List<Student> fetchAllStudentDeatil {     return studentRepo.findAll();  }
```

Also make sure that the method on GetMapping is not static . In case it is, make the  fetchAllStudentDeatil  also static.

Comment: I already have defined fetchAllStudentDeatil inside student service. How  to make  fetchAllStudentDeatil static.

Comment: by adding the keyword static in the method definition. I have updated my answer . let me know if it helps or some other error persist

Comment: Singh Thank you, But in Controller class "fetchAllStudentDeatil" is non-static . I don't want to make service ,repo or entity class methods static because there are many other methods depending on those classes. Is there any other way?

Comment: please share your controller class, student service and the repo. it will be easier to assist. Having said that, the error you quoted usually comes when we try to access non static method from a static block of code.