# Spring boot version changes to 2.6.6 from 2.3.4.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have changed the spring boot version to 2.6.6 from 2.3.4.RELEASE because of security vulnerabilities. My application's deployment is failing.

In pom.xml I have changed the version of only springboot.
`<spring.boot.version>2.6.6</spring.boot.version>`

Error Log:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field ''; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field ''; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field ''; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field ''; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field ''; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name '': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?"

Answer (score 2):

Well the error message states

```
Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?"
```

Usually spring boot displays the services for which the circularity was detected. I personally had this problem in the past. The dependency injection is not 100% deterministic and some unrelated changes in your project are now ending up in the detection of such an circular dependency. I am guessing that you are using

```
@Autowired
```

to inject you dependencies? When using constructor injection such problems are no longer exist [Spring @Autowire on Properties vs Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620000/spring-autowire-on-properties-vs-constructor)

For now you sadly don´t have any other options then to resolve your circular dependency.

If i am wrong here you need to show more of your exception. from what little that we have it is hard to conclude what is going on :)

Comment: There is a solution of circular dependency by using @Lazy, it's solved my issue, but for the moment I don't know what's the impacts on my code behind of using this

Answer (score 1):

spring-boot family starting from 2.6.X not allowing circular reference
you can add to your properties this line:

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

Answer (score 0):

@GJohannes The code is tightly coupled and in many places, I am using @Autowired. Instead of this can I use spring.main.allow-circular-references=true

Comment: Please comment on my answer so that i get a notification ;). You could certainly try your property. I honestly never heard of it before. Let me know about the outcome

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).