# Springboot dependency management design

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns

Below is the scenario where I need a solution.
class B is a generic solution where I need to inject different instances of C.
A and X will call B and B will work with the corresponding instances of C.

I need a List as well autowired to class B, since B object is created using new operator its not possible, and I dont want to pass List through constructor.

What would be the ideal solution?

I could have passed the C object in the b.method argument but thats not a good practise I presume.

```
@Bean(name="instance1")
 public B createB() {
 return new B(new C("value1"));
 }

---------------------

@Bean(name="instance2")
 public B createB() {
 return new B(new C("value2"));
 }

---------------------

public class A {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("instance1")
private B b;
 
b.method();

}

---------------------

public class X {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("instance2")
private B b;
 
b.method();

}

---------------------

public class B {

@Autowired
private List<D> dList;

B(C c) {
this.c = c;
}
c.method();
dList.forEach(d -> //do something);

}
```

---

Comment: The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection and has nothing against constructors. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620000/spring-autowire-on-properties-vs-constructor) covers constructor injection and this Spring doc [Constructor-based or setter-based DI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/dependencies/factory-collaborators.html#beans-constructor-vs-setter-injection). People use @Autowired on fields due to laziness. Also: [@Autowired docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/autowired.html).